# Cocos2d iPhone : Sprite initialized weird issue

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

I am using the [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/352/how-to-make-a-simple-iphone-game-with-cocos2d-tutorial) to make one simple app. And unlike the sample app, I want to show my projectile/object from the very beginning instead of on touch. For the same, I am doing like this :

```
-(id) init
{
    if((self=[super init]))
    {
        [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine]setEnabled:TRUE];
        winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;
        projectile = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"abc.png"];
        projectile.position = spriteOffset;
        self addChild:projectile];
        self.isTouchEnabled = YES;
        //some other code
   }
}
```

And then on touch of the same object/projectile, I need to move it to the direction i have moved it to. I am doing the below for the same :

```
- (void)ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    // Choose one of the touches to work with
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
    location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];

    // Determine offset of location to projectile
    int offX = location.x - projectile.position.x; //Projectile returns 0X0 here
    int offY = location.y - projectile.position.y;

    float scalarX = 1.0f;

    if (offX < 0.0f)
        scalarX = -1.0f;

    int realX = scalarX * (winSize.width + (projectile.contentSize.width/2));//winSize.width + (food.contentSize.width/2);
    float ratio = (float) offY / (float) offX;
    int realY = (realX * ratio) + projectile.position.y;
    CGPoint realDest = ccp(realX, realY);

    int offRealX = realX - projectile.position.x;
    int offRealY = realY - projectile.position.y;
    float length = sqrtf((offRealX*offRealX)+(offRealY*offRealY));
    float velocity = 480/1; // 480pixels/1sec
    float realMoveDuration = length/velocity;

    [projectile runAction:[CCSequence actions:
                       [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:realMoveDuration position:realDest],
                       [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(spriteMoveFinished:)],
                       nil]];
    [_projectiles addObject:projectile];  //ERROR SIGABRT

}
```

In the above code, at this line `int offX = location.x - projectile.position.x;` my sprite returns into 0X0. I am not getting where i am making mistake. At the first, it shows the objects on the screen but on touch event, it gets disappeared. I also have synthesized the CCSprite but in vail. Is there any other way around or any mistake that I am performing? Please help if any idea. Thank you.

```
ERROR : Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableArray insertObject:atIndex:]: attempt to insert nil object at 0'
```

Comment: CCLOG both location.x and projectile.position.x and post the values...also post the code where you update the projectile position

Comment: @Shubhank : Thank you for quick response. location.x = 156 while projectile.position.x results into 0. Also I edited my question and added the code in touch event and also the error log.

Comment: is your projectile declared in the same file or .h file? Please Check that because the projectile sprite doesn't get the memory. Also you didn't use _projectiles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; as in the tutorial under the init method

Comment: I know, I have declared in in .h file and also have done @property(nonatomic,retain) CCSprite *projectile; and hence the problem occurs. That is what is weird. I have done _projectiles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; in init method but I thought it is not that necessary to mention so have not shown here.

Comment: NSLog offX  after this line    int offX = location.x - projectile.position.x; //Projectile returns 0X0 here

Comment: It is same as location.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, since the projectile sprite is added as child in init, the only way it will be autoreleased is if elsewhere in the code the projectile is removed as child. You have to find where that is happening. Just forcing it to be 'sticky' with a retain may corrupt the logic about the sprite removal reason(s).

Answer (score 1):

`projectile` might be becoming a victim of autorelease pool and hence returning `0x0`.
as `projectile` is being initialized as non retained. 
this is not a COCOS2D related issue. this is basically a Objective-C memory management issue.

do one thing, make projectile as

> @property(nonatomic,retain)

then in

```
-(id) init
```

make this change:

> ```
>         self.projectile = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"abc.png"];
>         self.projectile.position = spriteOffset;
>         [self addChild:self.projectile];
> ```

hope this will resolve the issue you are facing

Comment: samfisher : Thank you.but I already have done so. I have mentioned the same thing in my post that I have @synthesize my CCSprite.

Comment: Actually, since the projectile sprite is added as child in init, the only way it will be autoreleased is if elsewhere in the code the projectile is removed as child. You have to find where that is happening. Just forcing it to be 'sticky' with a retain may corrupt the logic about the sprite removal reason(s).

Comment: i believe you are not using "self.projectile" after declaring it as retain property? if not just use the projectile with "self."

Comment: @YvesLeBorg : I am removing the chile but that is happening after the touch action is ended in spriteMoveFinished method but here the problem is that it is not at all moved.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg : your idea worked. thank you. how about posting your answer so that I can accept it..!! :)